# stack build results in ExitFailure 1 with Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I'm trying to get started with Yesod development on Windows, but I cannot seem to build the generated bare app. I followed all the [quick start guide](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) steps. Specifically, it fails on step 4, when I execute the

```
stack build
```

command. The following output is generated.

```
C:\Users\Vitor Coimbra\testeyesod>stack build
Setting codepage to UTF-8 (65001) to ensure correct output from GHC
Teste-0.0.0: build
Preprocessing library Teste-0.0.0...
In-place registering Teste-0.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'Teste' for Teste-0.0.0...
Linking .stack-work\dist\x86_64-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Teste\Teste.exe ...
ghc.exe: could not execute: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.2-a\lib/../mingw/bin/gcc.exe
ghc: warning: _tzset from msvcrt is linked instead of __imp__tzset

--  While building package Teste-0.0.0 using:
      C:\\Program Files\\Haskell Platform\\7.10.2-a\\bin\\runhaskell.exe -package=Cabal-1.22.4.0 -clear-package-db -global-package-db -package-db=C:\Users\Vitor Coimbra\AppData\Roaming\stack\snapshots\x86_64-windows\lts-3.1\7.10.2\pkgdb\ C:\Users\VITORC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\stack5620\Setup.hs --builddir=.stack-work\dist\x86_64-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\ build exe:Teste --ghc-options -hpcdir .stack-work\dist\x86_64-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\hpc\.hpc\ -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

The project was created with the name Teste and with SQLite as the persistence layer.

Comment: This looks somewhat like [issue 795](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/795) and/or the related issue 466.

Comment: If that's the problem, [this workaround(https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/08/stack-ghc-windows#workaround--shorter-paths) may help out.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comments. Unfortunately, the workaround mentioned by Michael was not enough for me. I guess I'll have to wait until this gets completely addressed then?